# Parallel Computer Simulator

Tags: haskell, language-agnostic, parallel-processing, developer-tools

I am using Haskell, which reported to be great and easy for parallelism. Unfortunately, I have no way to test this claim, as my computer has a single processor. Does anyone know of a utility that will make it appear as if my computer as 2 or 4(obviously slower than the real one) processors, and would let me track there performance.  It should also let me test one imaginary processor at a time, so I could see how parallel to nonparallel would compare on such a computer. Although it would be better to the comunity for a more universal app, I will take answers even if they only work with haskell.

P.S. I am running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Possibly answered here: [How can I emulate more virtual CPU than physically available?](http://serverfault.com/q/9313/135336).

Comment: If you want to simulate GPU parallelism, Accelerate offers a simulated backend I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The search keywords you are looking for are "simulate multiple cores"

Here's one: [sniper](http://snipersim.org/w/The_Sniper_Multi-Core_Simulator)

It is *not* open source.  From [the FAQ](http://snipersim.org/w/Frequently_Asked_Questions):

> Q: What are the license terms for using Sniper?
>
> A: In short, the interval core model is protected under a US patent
>   application. We automatically grant you a free license for using the
>   interval model inside Sniper for academic purposes. For commercial
>   use, please contact Lieven Eeckhout. All other code is licensed under
>   the very liberal MIT license. You can view the full details on our
>   License page.